# Monthly % of returning users in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to find out what percentage of users in a specific month return the next month.

This is my code:

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS month,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `table`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    curr.year,
    curr.month AS current_month,
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN prev.user_pseudo_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.year = prev.year AND curr.month - 1 = prev.month AND curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id
  GROUP BY
    curr.year, current_month
)
SELECT
  year,
  current_month,
  returning_user_count,
  total_users,
  (returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users) AS return_percentage
FROM
  returning_users
ORDER BY
  year, current_month;
```

The problem is that I am getting return_percentage greater than 100000!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`total_users` is the total count of **distinct** users whereas `returning_user_count` is the number of user returns, so if someone returns 10 times, his returns add 10 to the return count. It seems that you could solve the issue by replacing

```
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN prev.user_pseudo_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS returning_user_count,
```

with

```
COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
```